# regex find initials in sentence

Tags: python, regex

I want to test if a string contains initials such as 'A.' or 'B. M.'.

Why is

```
    bool(re.search("\b[A-Z]\.\b", 'A.'))
```

returning False?

Comment: Remove the last word boundary.

Comment: `r"\b[A-Z]\."`. Use a raw string literal. If you want to avoid matching `A.` in `A.Smith` you may use `r"\b[A-Z]\.(?!\w)"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't any word boundary after the dot, just remove it from the pattern:

```
re.search(r"\b[A-Z]\.", 'A.')
```